# C Macro to Create Bitfield Defines

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

**The Problem**

I am doing some firmware coding and have a lot of bitmasks to manage.  Until now, I have been repeating the same block for each field I want to mask as follows:

```
#define LinkStateMask  0x1
#define LinkStateShift 8
#define LinkState(x)  (((x) >> LinkStateShift) & LinkStateMask)
```

Note that the fields are quite often multi-bit fields so the mask is not always guaranteed to be `0x1`.  The final macro can be used in the code quite readably and this is something I quite like:

```
if( LinkState(temp) == 0 ) {
    // Link is down, return error
    return -ENODEV;
}
```

**The Question**

Is there any way to have the C preprocessor generate these macros for me?  I know that the preprocessor only works in a single pass so a macro cannot directly define another but hopefully there is another way.

Ideally, I would like to write something similar to the following and use the same C code as my second listing above:

```
BIT_FIELD(LinkState, 8, 0x1)         // BIT_FIELD(name, lsb, mask)
```

The key for me is keeping the symbolically named, function-style usage in the main C file without having to write the whole `BIT_FIELD(...)` invocation each time I need to generate a mask (some of these fields are used extensively, leading to a maintenance nightmare).

One final restriction: the fields I need are sparsely scattered across hundreds of registers.  If at all possible, I would *really* like to avoid having to define a `struct` for each as I usually only need one or two fields out of each.

Comment: cpp cannot **generate** macros! Use a code-generator (e.g. written in Python) to generate an appropriate header.

Comment: I don't see any bitfields here.

Comment: Make a macro that generates inline functions.

Comment: @ddriver: [SO 11815894](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815894/how-to-read-write-arbitrary-bits-in-c-c/27592777#27592777) is interesting, but the top-rated answer is C++ only in practice, though the ideas could be revised to make it work with C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Art](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939410/art) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253045/c-macro-to-create-bitfiteld-defines#comment50503547_31253045), one possibility is to use a macro to create an inline function:

```
#define BIT_FIELD(name, lsb, mask) \
        static inline int name(int value) { return (value >> (lsb)) & (mask); }
```

The parentheses are needed for `lsb` and `mask`, in case someone gets fancy with the invocation.

You can then create functions as needed:

```
BIT_FIELD(LinkState, 8, 0x1)
```

and invoke them when needed:

```
int x = LinkState(y);
```

The macro definition and invocations can go in a header — though there's no harm if there are invocations local to a specific file.

> Is there any major performance hit for doing this as a function versus doing this as a pre-computed value?

There's unlikely to be any performance hit because, for a function this simple, the compiler will inline all the code, exactly as if you'd used a macro, and with no function overhead.  Yes, there's a chance that your compiler is broken (or doesn't support C99 or C11 — `inline` was added to C99).  It's tempting to say "get a better compiler".  Test, measure, but there shouldn't be overhead.

If that's actually a problem, then you have to fall back on indirect alternatives.  For example, you could create a file `bitfields.hdr` containing:

```
#define BIT_HASH #
#define BIT_FIELD(name, lsb, mask) \
        BIT_HASH define name(value) (((value) >> (lsb)) & (mask))

BIT_FIELD(LinkState, 8, 0x1)
```

You could then arrange to compile it into a header file:

```
cpp -E bitfield.hdr > bitfield.h
```

With the `cpp` from GCC 5.1.0, I get the output:

```
# 1 "bitfield.hdr"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "bitfield.hdr"




 # define LinkState(value) (((value) >> (8)) & (0x1))
```

You can then use `#include "bitfield.h"` in the working code.  This is a simple form of code generation.  You could use an alternative macro processor if you preferred; `m4` would be the obvious alternative, but you could use anything that takes your fancy (`awk`, `perl`, `python`, `ruby` — any of them could be used).

Or you can do as [Felix Palmen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2371524/felix-palmen) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31253985/15168) — that's better and simpler than precompiling as suggested.  I'd be tempted to go with the inline functions as long as they work as expected, but Felix's suggestion is what to use if they don't.

Comment: Your edit is really fancy ... why rely on external tools when you can exploit the preprocessor like this? very nice! I'll have to remember this trick.

Comment: First invocation worked for me using `static inline`, though the method in the edit is really spiffy, too.  Will have to keep that in my back pocket for a rainy day.

Answer (score 5):

A macro cannot **define** another macro, but it can **call** another one (the preprocessor won't stop until there are no non-terminals left)

So, how about something like this? at least saves some typing ...

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SHIFTMASK(x,s,m) (((x) >> (s)) & (m))

#define LinkState(x) SHIFTMASK(x, 8, 0x1)
#define Whatever(x) SHIFTMASK(x, 9, 0x7)

int test[] = { 0x0f00, 0x0a01, 0x0100, 0x0007 };

int main()
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        printf("test[%d]: 0x%x\n", i, test[i]);
        printf("LinkState(test[%d]): 0x%x\n", i, LinkState(test[i]));
        printf("Whatever(test[%d]): 0x%x\n", i, Whatever(test[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please enclose both `s` and `m` in parentheses, so that things don't go haywire if someone tries `#define AnotherMask(x) SHIFTMASK(x, NODE&7, 0x3C | 0x04)`, for example.  But that's trivia for improving an otherwise very sensible answer.

Comment: Well I thought about this, doesn't seem the original poster's use case -- but add them nevertheless cause they don't hurt.

Comment: Agreed, the original use case would have no problem, but code is seldom only used in the original use case, and making it (more nearly) bullet-proof is a minimal cost — two pairs of parentheses.

Comment: You're totally right about this, I should really know from my job ... next time I'll do the "bullet-proof" edit without waiting for a comment ;)

Comment: You raise an excellent point about not having to define a new macro.  Jonathan's solution is the one I ended up using but this will definitely be useful on our older platforms that still use C89.

Comment: That's great, I'm still impressed by the preprocessor "black magic" ;) I chose the *straight forward* way here and I'm thankful it's appreciated. Nevertheless, Jonathan presented the solution closer to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Another trick, which might be even nicer, is defining bit fields using a ternary operator.

These macros handle the interpretation :

```
// Extract starting and ending bit number from a bit_range,
// defined as the arguments for a ternary operator (low:high).
// Example : #define Least3Bits 0:2
#define BitRange(StartBit, BitCount) (StartBit):(StartBit+BitCount-1)
#define BitRangeStart(bit_range) (1?bit_range)
#define BitRangeEnd(bit_range) (0?bit_range)

#define BitRangeMask(bit_range) ((~0 << BitRangeStart(bit_range)) ^ (~0 << BitRangeEnd(bit_range)))
#define BitRangeShift(bit_range) BitRangeStart(bit_range)
#define BitRangeValue(bit_range, value) (((value) & BitRangeMask(bit_range)) >> BitRangeShift(bit_range))
```

Now your example can be declared like this :

```
#define LinkState_BitRange BitRange(8, 1)
#define LinkState(value) BitRangeValue(LinkState_BitRange, value)
```

And the other example :

```
#define Whatever_BitRange BitRange(9, 3)
#define Whatever(x) BitRangeValue(Whatever_BitRange, value)
```

Declaring the bit ranges incorrectly will lead to compile errors, so this is quite a safe method to use too.

Answer (score 0):

Combining Jonathan's and Felix's answers with my own favorite preprocessor trick **X-Macros** yields the following.

```
#define Fields(_) \
    _(Link, 0x1, 8) \
/*enddef Fields() */

#define HASH #
#define GenState(name, mask, shift) \
    HASH define name ## State (((x) >> (shift)) & (mask))

Fields(GenState)
```

To which additional fields may be easily added to the table.

`cpp -P` yields:

```
 # define LinkState (((x) >> (8)) & (0x1))
```

The `-P` option suppresses all the unneeded "information" directive lines in the output.