# stretch mask - bit manipulation

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I want to stretch a mask in which every bit represents 4 bits of stretched mask.
I am looking for an elegant bit manipulation to stretch using c++ and systemC

**for example:**

input:

```
mask (32 bits) = 0x0000CF00
```

output:

```
stretched mask (128 bits) = 0x00000000 00000000 FF00FFFF 00000000
```

and just to clarify the example let's look at the the byte C:

```
0xC = 1100 after stretching: 1111111100000000 = 0xFF00
```

Comment: Is `_pdep_u32` allowed?

Comment: Do you want to stretch any amount of bits like 17, 78, ... or do you only need multiples of 16 or 32?

Comment: Can you explain what the underlying problem that you're actually solving is?  Stretching a mask like this sounds like a very strange operation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815894/how-to-read-write-arbitrary-bits-in-c-c/27592777#27592777

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this in a elegant form is not easy.
The simple mode maybe is create a loop with shift bit

```
sc_biguint<128> result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
    if(bit_test(var, i)){
        result +=0x0F;
    }
    result << 4;
}
```

Comment: Note that `result` needs a type which is at least 32*4=128bit large.

Comment: Yes, so, I believe that you can create a variable type ou use a vector

Comment: I am using SystemC libraries so I have sc_biguint<128>.
missing parenthesis in 3rd line.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way of stretching a 16-bit mask into 64 bits where every bit represents 4 bits of stretched mask:

```
uint64_t x = 0x000000000000CF00LL;

x = (x | (x << 24)) & 0x000000ff000000ffLL;
x = (x | (x << 12)) & 0x000f000f000f000fLL;
x = (x | (x << 6)) & 0x0303030303030303LL;
x = (x | (x << 3)) & 0x1111111111111111LL;
x |= x << 1;
x |= x << 2;
```

It starts of with the mask in the bottom 16 bits. Then it moves the top 8 bits of the mask into the top 32 bits, like this:

```
0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
```

becomes

```
0000000000000000 00000000ABCDEFGH 0000000000000000 00000000IJKLMNOP
```

Then it solves the similar problem of stretching a mask from the bottom 8 bits of a 32 bit word, to the top and bottom 32-bits simultaneously:

```
000000000000ABCD 000000000000EFGH 000000000000IJKL 000000000000MNOP
```

Then it does it for 4 bits inside 16 and so on until the bits are spread out:

```
000A000B000C000D 000E000F000G000H 000I000J000K000L 000M000N000O000P
```

Then it "smears" them across 4 bits by ORing the result with itself twice:

```
AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD EEEEFFFFGGGGHHHH IIIIJJJJKKKKLLLL MMMMNNNNOOOOPPPP
```

You could extend this to 128 bits by adding an extra first step where you shift by 48 bits and mask with a 128-bit constant:

```
x = (x | (x << 48)) & 0x000000000000ffff000000000000ffffLLL;
```

You'd also have to stretch the other constants out to 128 bits just by repeating the bit patterns. However (as far as I know) there is no way to declare a 128-bit constant in C++, but perhaps you could do it with macros or something ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188939/representing-128-bit-numbers-in-c)). You could also make a 128-bit version just by using the 64-bit version on the top and bottom 16 bits separately.

If loading the masking constants turns out to be a difficulty or bottleneck you can generate each one from the previous one using shifting and masking:

```
uint64_t m = 0x000000ff000000ffLL;

m &= m >> 4; m |= m << 16;  // gives 0x000f000f000f000fLL
m &= m >> 2; m |= m << 8;  // gives 0x0303030303030303LL
m &= m >> 1; m |= m << 4; // gives 0x1111111111111111LL
```

Comment: The last two instructions `(x |= x<<2; x |= x<<1)` can be replaced by `x*=0xf`

Comment: It looks like the masks can also be pairwised combined. That is to say, you can start with `(x *= (1+1ULL<<12+1ULL<<24+1ULL<<36)`. You'll have a few positions where bits collide, but you mask those out anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long Stretch4x(int input)
{
    long long output = 0;

    while (input & -input)
    {
        int b = (input & -input);
        long long s = 0;
        input &= ~b;
        s = b*15;
        while(b>>=1)
        {
            s <<= 3;
        }

        output |= s;
    }
    return output;  
}

int main(void) {
    int input = 0xCF00;

    printf("0x%0x ==> 0x%0llx\n", input, Stretch4x(input));
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
0xcf00 ==> 0xff00ffff00000000
```

Answer (score 2):

The other solutions are good. However, most them are more C than C++. This solution is pretty straight forward: it uses `std::bitset` and set four bits for each input bit.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

std::bitset<128> 
starch_32 (const std::bitset<32> &input)
{
    std::bitset<128> output;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
        // If `input[N]` is `true`, set `output[N*4, N*4+4]` to true.
        if (input.test (i)) {
            const size_t output_index = i * 4;

            output.set (output_index);
            output.set (output_index + 1);
            output.set (output_index + 2);
            output.set (output_index + 3);
        }
    }

    return output;
}

// Example with 0xC. 
int main() {
    std::bitset<32> input{0b1100};

    auto result = starch_32 (input);

    std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << result.to_ullong() << "\n";
}
```

[Try it online!](https://ideone.com/z3HtTD)

Answer (score 1):

On x86 you could use the `PDEP` [intrinsic](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/X86-Built-in-Functions.html) to move the 16 mask bits into the correct nibble (into the low bit of each nibble, for example) of a 64-bit word, and then use a couple of shift + or to smear them into the rest of the word:

```
unsigned long x = _pdep_u64(m, 0x1111111111111111);
x |= x << 1;
x |= x << 2;
```

You could also replace those two OR and two shift by a single multiplication by `0xF` which accomplishes the same smearing.

Finally, you could consider a SIMD approach: solutions such as samgak's above should map naturally to SIMD.